# Testing response AND function call of library using fetch with Jest + node-fetch + fetch-mock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, fetch, jestjs

I'm writing a JavaScript/React library which uses `fetch`.

I'm using Jest in order to test this library, and what I'd like to achieve is :

1. Mock HTTP requests in order to not send real calls and manipulate the answers (mock the backend server) so I'm using `fetch-mock`
2. Test the passed parameters to the `fetch` function

In order to achieve the first point, I need to do

```
fetchMock.post(`${API_URL}/sessions`, {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    token: 'this-is-your-token'
  }),
  status: 201
})
```

In order to achieve the second point, I need to do

```
const spiedFetch = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch')
// ...
expect(spiedFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

*(The last line is within a series of `describe()` and `it()`).*

I have a first test which ensures the response has the `token` field and so on, and the second test is ensuring that `fetch` has been called once.

When I run them, the first one passes, then second one fails. When I comment the `fetchMock.post(...)`, the first one fails and the second one passes.

Based on this, I guess `fetch-mock` and `jest.spyOn` are incompatible.

Questions :

1. Am I right thinking `fetch-mock` and `jest.spyOn` are incompatible?
2. How can I achieve the testing of the `fetch` response AND the passed parameters? (I want to ensure the HTTP verb is this, and the passed headers are that).
3. A way I could think of is to use `fetch-mock` as is, but using `jest.spyOn` on a function of my lib, which would embed `fetch`. Is that an okay way of doing it?

**UPDATE:** I tried my point 3 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

`jest.spyOn` [replaces the original function with a wrapper](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/2d972e5470c0e3365a2763279982ebf303136c0a/packages/jest-mock/src/index.js#L766-L768).

`const fetchMock = require('fetch-mock');` doesn't immediately change the global `fetch`, but [as soon as a function like `fetchMock.get`](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/bbec30b7a10648ec6c654a10f316127bc40ebb9f/src/lib/set-up-and-tear-down.js#L98) is called [it replaces the global `fetch`](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/bbec30b7a10648ec6c654a10f316127bc40ebb9f/src/lib/set-up-and-tear-down.js#L68).

Because they both work by modifying the global `fetch` they can be tricky to use together.

As it turns out, every time a method like `fetchMock.get` is called the global `fetch` gets replaced, but if `jest.spyOn` is called *after* all such methods are called on `fetchMock` then they will actually both work since `jest.spyOn` will wrap and track the final replaced `fetch`.

Having said that, there isn't really a need to use `jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch')` if you are already using `fetch-mock` since `fetch-mock` provides access to all the calls that were made to `fetch`.

To assert on the calls directly you can [access them using `fetchMock.calls()`](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-inspectioncalls).

Even easier is to [simply call `fetchMock.done()`](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-inspectiondone) at the end of the test to assert that `fetch` was used exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I'll give it a try !